# <Live by one's age> VS <Live based on one's age> VS <Live according to one's age>

Tags: word-usage, idiomatic-language, phrase-choice, collocations

Can we use the phrases **"Live by one's age"**, **"Live based on one's age"** and **"Live according to one's age"** interchangeably to mean living in a way that represents your age?

For example, do you think these example sentences are idiomatic?

> **I think people should be themselves instead of living by their age.**

> **I think people should be themselves instead of living based on their age.**

> **I think people should be themselves instead of living according to their age.**

I researched what structure to use when expressing this, but I could not find any proper information.

Comment: The idiomatic standard in English is ***Act your age**!* But don't say it to an adult - it's very rude. I don't think there's any succinct way to convey in English what you seem to have in mind, though. *People should just be themselves, rather than try to conform to the social norms [assumed to be] appropriate to their age band* might be as good as you'll get.